# passlib.exc.MissingBackendError: bcrypt: no backends available -- recommend you install one

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, fastapi

Using AWS Lambda for execution where I get the error given below even though we had the mentioned package in libs, Already installed passlib library and bycrypt dependencies, also tried with different python versions for execution, same error keeps on coming, Have no clue on this

> 

```
[ERROR] 2021-12-19T07:18:10.597Z    9e6d8789-60d9-4b16-a8e7-4b20eacbdad9    Exception in 'http' protocol.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/mangum/protocols/http.py", line 81, in run
    await app(self.request.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/var/task/fastapi/applications.py", line 208, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/var/task/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/var/task/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 656, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 259, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/var/task/starlette/routing.py", line 61, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/var/task/fastapi/routing.py", line 226, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/var/task/fastapi/routing.py", line 161, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "/var/task/starlette/concurrency.py", line 39, in run_in_threadpool
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
  File "/var/task/anyio/to_thread.py", line 28, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(func, *args, cancellable=cancellable,
  File "/var/task/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 818, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "/var/task/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 754, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "/var/task/api/v1/endpoints/routers/authentication.py", line 37, in login
    if not Hash.verify(request.password, user.password):
  File "/var/task/api/v1/endpoints/utils/hashing.py", line 11, in verify
    return pwd_ctx.verify(plain_password, hashed_password)
  File "/var/task/passlib/context.py", line 2347, in verify
    return record.verify(secret, hash, **kwds)
  File "/var/task/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 792, in verify
    return consteq(self._calc_checksum(secret), chk)
  File "/var/task/passlib/handlers/bcrypt.py", line 591, in _calc_checksum
    self._stub_requires_backend()
  File "/var/task/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 2254, in _stub_requires_backend
    cls.set_backend()
  File "/var/task/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 2156, in set_backend
    return owner.set_backend(name, dryrun=dryrun)
  File "/var/task/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 2176, in set_backend
    raise default_error
passlib.exc.MissingBackendError: bcrypt: no backends available -- recommend you install one (e.g. 'pip install bcrypt')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with different versions of cryptography and bcrypt in requirements, there is a compatibility issue with GLIBC on AWS Lambda runtime

```
cryptography==3.4.8
bcrypt==3.2.2
```

Comment: cryptography==3.4.8 have some security issue

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you are working on a non-linux operating system whilst the AWS lambda works on linux based OS.  For example, the function may work on your windows machine but will throw that error on AWS Lambda. Instead of passlib, you may use bcrypt.

**The solution**

a) On AWS Lambda you could simply use bcrypt instead of passlib.

```
import bcrypt as s5_bcrypt
```

b)
and ensure that the dependencies are installed within the lambda project folder using the manylinux2014_x86_64 platform flat.

```
cd <project-folder>
pip install --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --implementation cp -python-version 3.9 --only-binary=:all: --upgrade bcrypt -t .
```

And in the code call bcrypt using the alias s5_bcrypt

```
s5_bcrypt.checkpw(plain_secret, hashed)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html#python-image-base

see that py311 is on al2: uses glibc 2_24

py312 is on al2023: uses glibc 2_28 I believe

When you install bcrypt>4, it necessarily depends on glib 2_28, which al2 does not provide.

Also if you are building on a mismatched version of python you will also fail. Make sure that you are building on the same python version, os, arch as the lambda environment, and then downgrade to bcrypt 3

alternatively you can move to a python312 lambda environment